# What are the two console windows in Visual Studio 2017 when pushing code to GitHub?

Tags: windows, git, github, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio 2017 and every time I push code to GitHub, there are two console windows which open and close. I have Visual Studio GitHub extension plugin installed.
There weren't these console windows in Visual Studio 2015.
What are they for?

Comment: There are no DOS windows in Windows. You are probably referring to command prompts. Please update your question and question tags.

Comment: run [ProcessMonitor during push](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and analyze the log to see the commandline of the cmd.exe processes.